# Why is my function not working in Python? I defined the list, but it says I haven't

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_student_list():
    iStr = ""
    stdlist = []
    x = 1
    while not iStr == "quit":
        iStr = input(f'Please enter a new student name, ("quit" if no more student)')
        if not iStr == "quit":
            stdlist.append(iStr)
        elif iStr == "":
            print("Empty student name is not allowed.")
        x += 1
print(f'The whole class list is {sum(stdList)}')
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

I'm expecting the user input student into list and end when they type quit. Or when it's empty, print empty student name is not allowed

Comment: stdList is local to your function ... it does not exist outside of the scope of your function ... you either need to return it or make it global... or put the print also inside of your function

Comment: `stdList` is only defined inside the `get_student_list` function. Your last line is outside the function.

Comment: And if you fix that, `sum(stdList)` doesn't make sense as it is a list of names.

Comment: The standard idiom for this would be `while True: iStr = ...; if iStr == "quit": break; ...`, rather than initializing `iStr` to a "known" non-terminating value before the loop.

Comment: you don't need the variable `x`. If you want the total number of students you can always do `len(stdlist)` afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some things in your code and made it more readable

```
def get_student_list():
    stdlist = []

    while True:
        iStr = input('Please enter a new student name, ("quit" if no more student)')
        if iStr == "quit":
            return stdlist 
        elif iStr == "":
            print("Empty student name is not allowed.")
        else: 
            stdlist.append(iStr)

stdList = get_student_list()
print(f"You have a total of {len(stdList)} students:")
for i, name in enumerate(stdList):
    print(f"  {i+1})  {name}")
```

This will return:

```
You have a total of 3 students:
  1) Bob Marley
  2) Michael Jackson
  3) Elvis Presley
```

Answer (score 1):

your list is defined in the function and your print is global so it won't work ^^
you can either define stdlist as a global (outside your function) or indent your print

Comment: defining a global is a bad idea. the OP should return the list as suggested by others

Comment: not to mention other issues with this code....

Answer (score 0):

The list `stdlist` is local to the function `get_student_list()`. Your last `print` does not have access to it.

To fix:

```py
def get_student_list():
    # All your code here
    return stdlist

stdlist = get_student_list()
print(f'The whole class list is {sum(stdlist)}')
```

Comment: that line will just give a different error now ...

Comment: the sum of a list of strings doesnt make sense

Comment: That is another matter.

Comment: But that matter prevents this answer from working. Maybe you want to put your print inside a loop that iterates each name in the list

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I do not know what the OP's intention is in order to fix that problem. That's topic for another question.